# Why is the output wrong

Tags: java, l-systems

I should be getting a tree.
But I am not getting a tree.
I am getting a long thing, not a tree.

This is my code:

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Main() {

    setTitle("Tree");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setResizable(false);

    add(new TreeDrawer(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //button shit
    JButton generate = new JButton("Generate");
    generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            TreeDrawer.generate();
            repaint();
        }
    });

    add(generate, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new Main();
    });

    }

}
```

**TreeDrawer.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class TreeDrawer extends JComponent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int ROOM_WIDTH = 1080;
public static final int ROOM_HEIGHT = 720 - 47;// 47 is the height of menu bar on top of jframe or some shit
static double len = 100; the length of each branch shit

public TreeDrawer() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT));
}

private static String axiom = "F";
private static String sentence = axiom;

private static Graphics2D graphics;

//this shit will change on vary of l system, new rules and etc
private static String rules(char a) {
    if(a == 'F')//a rule
        return "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]";
    return "";//if nothing else works, shit
}

//generates the whole shit
    //probably correct
public static void generate() {
    len *= 0.5;//shrink the shit
    String nextSentence = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        char current = sentence.charAt(i);
        nextSentence += rules(current);
    }
    sentence = nextSentence;
    System.out.println(sentence);
    turtle();
}

public static void turtle() {

    AffineTransform transform = null;//so you can save shit

    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        char current = sentence.charAt(i);

        if(current == 'F') {//draw up
            graphics.drawLine(0, 0, 0, (int) -len);
            graphics.translate(0, -len);
        }

        else if(current == '+') {//right turn
            graphics.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
        }

        else if(current == '-') {//left turn
            graphics.rotate(-Math.PI / 6);
        }
        //probably wrong shit
        else if(current == '[') {//save transformations

            transform = graphics.getTransform();
        }
        //also probably wrong shit
        else if(current == ']') {//restore from last save
            graphics.setTransform(transform);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//so that shit is drawn
    graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    graphics.translate(ROOM_WIDTH / 2, ROOM_HEIGHT - 10);
    graphics.setPaint(Color.WHITE);

    turtle();

}
}
```

What did I do wrong. I can not figure out how to post a screenshot of the output that I got, but it looks completely off of what is correct. I know that my algorithm of the L-system is right, because that is working well. But I think that when I try to save and restore the transformation state, something goes wrong. Saving the transformation state is the brackets ([ and ]. '[' saves, ']' restores from that save). But I do not know what is wrong. I need help to find what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Observation, you should not be maintaining a reference to `Graphics` for any longer then you need to, instead, you should pass the reference to your `turtle` method

Comment: Take a screenshot and save it on your computer. Then edit your question and press CTRL + G to upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Observations...

1. If you didn't create the instance of `Graphics`, you should not maintain a reference to it for any longer than you need to use it.  Instead, you should pass it as a parameter to the methods that need to use it.  This will save you from some serious weird artefacts and possible `NullPointerException`s
2. If you are going to transform the `Graphics` context, you'd best to create a copy of it before you do, as it's a shared resource between all components getting painted.
3. In this context, `static` is NOT your friend and is poor design.

Taking all that into account, something like the following works...at a basic level

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TreeDrawer treeDrawer;

    public Main() {

        setTitle("Tree");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //setResizable(false);

        treeDrawer = new TreeDrawer();
        add(treeDrawer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //button shit
        JButton generate = new JButton("Generate");
        generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                treeDrawer.generate();
                repaint();
            }
        });

        add(generate, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Main();
        });

    }

    public class TreeDrawer extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static final int ROOM_WIDTH = 1080;
        public static final int ROOM_HEIGHT = 720 - 47;// 47 is the height of menu bar on top of jframe or some shit
        double len = 100;

        public TreeDrawer() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT));
        }

        private String axiom = "F";
        private String sentence = axiom;

        private String rules(char a) {
            if (a == 'F')//a rule
            {
                return "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]";
            }
            return "";//if nothing else works, shit
        }

        //probably correct
        public void generate() {
            len *= 0.5;//shrink the shit
            String nextSentence = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                char current = sentence.charAt(i);
                nextSentence += rules(current);
            }
            sentence = nextSentence;
            System.out.println(sentence);
//            turtle();
        }

        public void turtle(Graphics2D graphics) {

            AffineTransform transform = null;//so you can save shit

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                char current = sentence.charAt(i);

                if (current == 'F') {//draw up
                    graphics.drawLine(0, 0, 0, (int) -len);
                    graphics.translate(0, -len);
                } else if (current == '+') {//right turn
                    graphics.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
                } else if (current == '-') {//left turn
                    graphics.rotate(-Math.PI / 6);
                } //probably wrong shit
                else if (current == '[') {//save transformations

                    transform = graphics.getTransform();
                } //also probably wrong shit
                else if (current == ']') {//restore from last save
                    graphics.setTransform(transform);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {//so that shit is drawn
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            super.paintComponent(g2d);
            g2d.translate(ROOM_WIDTH / 2, ROOM_HEIGHT - 10);
            g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);

            turtle(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```